# Oracle Fusion Middleware vs. MySQL - DB Init Param Prerequisite failure

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm setting up an FMW sandbox environment on my laptop to play around. It needs a database as repository, I though MySQL would be simplest.
A battled a few problems I sorted out already, but I'm stuck with one.

Oracle Repository Creation Utility required sql_mode modules NO_ZERO_IN_DATE and NO_ZERO_DATE to be disabled. Currently this is set:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'select @@global.sql_mode'
Enter password: 
+-------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode |
+-------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES |
+-------------------+
```

I still get the following:

[image: RCU prerequisite failure]

What could be the problem?

FMW version: 12.2.1.3

MySQL version: 5.7.27

Comment: `From MySQL 5.7.4 through 5.7.7, STRICT_ALL_TABLES includes the effect of the ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_ZERO_DATE, and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE modes. `

Comment: You wrote MySQL [...] through 5.7.7, but in the original post I noted that I was trying with 5.7.27. Is that any different?